# Get working days DateTime List of two dates

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Im trying to get a List of working days between two dates but I got just from a month.

```
var workingDays = Enumerable.Range(1, daysInMonth)
                          .Where(d =>
                              !weekends.Contains(new DateTime(last30Days.Year, last30Days.Month, d).DayOfWeek)).ToList();
```

But this way i get just one speciefic month.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start out with a function to get all days between two dates:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> DaysBetween(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var current = start;
    if (current != current.Date) //handle the case where the date isn't already midnight
        current = current.AddDays(1).Date;
    while (current < end)
    {
        yield return current;
        current = current.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

Then just filter out the non-working days:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> WorkDayBetween(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    return DaysBetween(start, end)
        .Where(date => IsWorkDay(date));
}

//feel free to use alternate logic here, or to account for holidays, etc.
private static bool IsWorksDay(DateTime date)
{
    return date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday
                    && date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday;
}
```