# get monthwise working days between a given start date and end date

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I need to write a method where i will pass a start date and a end date . The output should be a list with two parametsrs . One is month name and other is no of working days in that month.  (removing sat and sun)

Please advise.

```
public List<MonthDaysData> GetMonthwiseWorkingdays(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
{
List<MonthDaysData> monthdays = new List<MonthDaysData>();

// Coding to get the output
return monthdays;
}

public class MonthDaysData 
{ 
  public Int32? Month { get; set; } 
  public Int32? days { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: So why don't just loop from start date to end, check if it's holiday or not and add it to list if nessesary? What have your tried so far?

Comment: provide MonthDaysData definition too.

Comment: public class MonthDaysData
    {
        public Int32? Month { get; set; }
        public Int32? days { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Hi andy , thanks for your response.. I can get the total days between the two date . but what i need is monthwise splitup of working days.

Comment: Sure chris. 
Say my start date is 25-Sep-2014 and end date is 05-nov-2014 .
I should get output as a list with three rows. 
("September" , 4)
("October" ,23 )
("November", 5).

Please help

Comment: What have you tried? Searching for "C# Get working days between two dates" yields _a lot_ of results. What should happen if the dates span more than a year?

Comment: As per my UI validation start date and end must be in same year. So there wont be any case of date range with different years.

Comment: @Ram, did my answer help since I did go to the trouble of writing the code!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an Extension Method to get the values like this...

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<MonthDaysData> GetWorkingDaysPerMonthTo(this DateTime from, 
                         DateTime to)
    {
        var workings = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        var currentDateTime = from;

        while (currentDateTime <= to)
        {
            if (currentDateTime.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday 
                                  && currentDateTime.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday 
                                  && !currentDateTime.IsHoliday("CountryCode"))
                if (!workings.ContainsKey(currentDateTime.Month))
                    workings.Add(currentDateTime.Month, 1);
                else
                {
                    int curWork;
                    workings.TryGetValue(currentDateTime.Month, out curWork);
                    curWork++;
                    workings.Remove(currentDateTime.Month);
                    workings.Add(currentDateTime.Month, curWork);
                }

            currentDateTime = currentDateTime.AddDays(1);
        }
        return workings.Select(work => new MonthDaysData {Month = work.Key, 
                                                       days = work.Value}).ToList();
    } 

    public static bool IsHoliday(this DateTime date, string countryCode)
    {
        // some service that takes a country code and 
        // returns true/false if its a holiday
        return false;
    }
}
```

You could then call it from anywhere like...

```
var today = new DateTime(2014, 10, 16);
var dates = today.GetWorkingDaysPerMonthTo(new DateTime(2014, 12, 16));
```

However, this is simply working with weekdays as working days, you would need to check public holidays etc.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework and you don't show what you have tried, so I'm not going to churn out all code for you. There are [quite some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C%23+working+days+between+two+dates) on this matter. See for example [Get working days DateTime List of two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236663/get-working-days-datetime-list-of-two-dates) for a simple implementation that returns a list of working day dates:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> workingDays = WorkDaysBetween(DateTime start, DateTime end);
```

You'll then have to group them by month as per your requirement:

```
var groupedByMonth = workingDays.GroupBy(d => new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, 1));
```

From there you must be able to `Select()` the proper projection.